# Перечисление полей структуры

Tags: c++, c++14, метапрограммирование

Есть структура и функции:

```
struct S {
    T1 t1;
    T2 t2;
    // и т.д.
} s;

template <class T> f(const T& t, const char* name) { /* что-то */ }
```

Необходимо, чтобы работал следующий (псевдо)код:

```
for (поле : поля(s))
    f(поле.значение, поле.имя);
```

То есть, надо как-то перечислить все поля структуры, получая их тип, значение и имя в виде строки.

Я знаю, что рефлексии в языке *C++* нет. Но здесь не нужна рефлексия при выполнении, нужна рефлексия на стадии компиляции или линковки. При этом можно как угодно извращаться с объявлением структуры `S`, но нельзя трогать функцию `f`. Но в итоге всё равно должна быть каким-либо образом создана либо структура либо что-то структурообразное, поволяющее обращаться к полям (`s.t1` и т.д.).

Сторонние библиотеки использовать нельзя, но можно использовать макросы, шаблоны и вообще все доступные возможности *C++14*.

Comment: Для решения Вашей задачи давно придумали такую штуку [X MACROS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro). Что бы его понять, придется сломать пару раз мозг, но потом все будет очевидно. Работает даже с самыми древними (разумно древними) компиляторами.

Comment: Без макросов никак. Даже Boost.Fusion [требует дополнительного макроопределения с перечислением типов полей структуры](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19068267/2553424).

Comment: Похожий вопрос на [enSO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17660095/3240681). Если нельзя использовать сторонние библиотеки, но надо просто всё это перетащить в свой код. Но это довольно глупо и наверное даже нелегально.

Comment: Я бы наверное не стал заморачиваться с метапрограммированием. Сделал бы `T1`, `T2` ... наследниками некоего `T0`. Структуру превратил бы в контейнер с элементами `T0*` и для всех типов определил бы виртуальные функции `f`. Тогда цикл был бы элементарным.

Comment: Если поля приходится итерировать - меняйте структуру данных. Сама по себе структура явно не для этого.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Как предложил в комментариях к вопросу @KoVadim, можно использовать так называемые ***[X Macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)***. С их использованием Ваша задача решается примерно следующим образом:

```
#include <iostream>

#define STRUCT_FIELDS \
    X(int, i) \
    X(float, f) \
    X(const char*, c)

struct S {
    #define X(type, name) type name;
        STRUCT_FIELDS
    #undef X
};

template<typename T> void f(const T& t, const char* name)
{
    std::cout << name << " = " << t << std::endl;
}

void printStruct(const S& s) {
    #define X(type, name) f(s.name, #name);
        STRUCT_FIELDS
    #undef X
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    S s;
    s.i = 1;
    s.f = 10.1;
    s.c = "s";

    printStruct(s);
}
```

Результат работы программы:

```
i = 1
f = 10.1
c = s
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что надо!

Answer (score 3):

Можно допилить мое [решение](https://github.com/BG4444/opt-parser). Оно предназначено для разбора параметров командной строки и помещения их в кортеж, к элементам которого можно обращаться по имени. При этом, имена на этапе компиляции заменяются на индексы элементов в кортеже.

Как с этим работать:

Нужно унаследовать класс от opt-parser

```
#ifndef CONVOPTIONS_H
#define CONVOPTIONS_H
#include "opt-parser/optparser.h"

struct optlist
{
    static constexpr auto options=tuple_cat(
                OPTPARSER::makeO<std::string>("input"),
                OPTPARSER::makeO<std::string>("output")
                );

};

class ConvOptions:public OPTPARSER::Options<optlist>
{
public:
    ConvOptions(int argc,char** argv);
};

#endif // CONVOPTIONS_H
```

После чего, можно обращаться к его полям по именам:

```
ConvOptions opts(argc,argv);
$(opts,"input")
```

Answer (score 1):

Это шкурка ответа с шагами его получения.
Надо ещё везде распихать ссылки и добавить поддержку имён полей.

1. http://ideone.com/6LOtIl
2. http://ideone.com/ac32bj
3. http://ideone.com/bG8q69
4. http://ideone.com/umN51y
5. http://ideone.com/bxgu9H
6. http://ideone.com/rddXvG

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename typed, int i = 0> struct enumerate
{
    static auto get(typed x) -> decltype(x.template get<i>()) { return x.template get<i>(); };
    const static bool has_next = !is_same<decltype(typed().template get<i+1>()), void>::value;
    typedef enumerate<typed, has_next?i+1:-1> next;

    template <template <class> class handler> static void go(typed x)
    {
        handler<decltype(get(x))>()(get(x));
        if (has_next) next::template go<handler>(x);
    }
};

template <typename typed> struct enumerate <typed, -1>
{
    static void get(typed x) {}
    const static bool has_next = false;
    typedef enumerate<typed, -1> next;

    template <template <class> class handler> static void go(typed x)
    {
    }
};

#define ENUMERABLE_FIELD(type, name, i) public: type name; \
                                        private: type get(key_t<i>) { return this->name; }

struct smth
{
    private: template <int i> struct key_t {};
    private: template <int i> void get(key_t<i>) {}

    ENUMERABLE_FIELD(int, x, 0)
    ENUMERABLE_FIELD(double, y, 1)

    public: template <int i> auto get() -> decltype(this->get(key_t<i>())) { return this->get(key_t<i>()); }
};

template <class typed> void print(const typed& t)
{
    cout << t << endl;
}

template <class typed> struct pass_to_print
{
    void operator () (typed t) { return print(t); }
};

int main()
{
    smth s = {1, 2.5};

    enumerate<smth>::go<pass_to_print>(s);

    return 0;
}
```