# C++ Как узнать список полей класса внутри template

Tags: c++, классы, c++11, шаблоны-с++

Хочу создать функцию которая будет пробегаться по всем полям класса и задавать им значения либо 0, если поле числовое, либо пустую строку, если поле строковое.

Что то вроде того `func<Class>(obj);`

По скольку все классы разные и поля у них разные, а в С++ почти нет ни какого рантайма, то видимо подобное должно делаться на этапе компиляции, видимо через шаблоны .

Подскажите возможно ли это, или движок шаблонов С++ не настолько развит чтобы делать такие вещи?

Возможно есть какой-то трюк с макросами?

Comment: Метаинформации о классах в C++ нет.

Comment: [Недавно обсуждалось подобное.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/624037/176217) А вообще надо просто конструктор по умолчанию задать.

Comment: @alexolut при чем здесь конструктор по умолчанию, если я хочу сделать мост из мира С++ в мир javascript в трансляторе Cheerp чтобы создавался скрипт обьект враппер который пересылал сигналы С++ обьекту. Для этого мне нужно знать четко каждое поле С++ класса. Чтобы руками не писать JS враппер на каждый С++ класс

Comment: При чем здесь какой-то мост в JS, если Вы в вопросе об этом ничего не написали? Задачи инициализации принято решать в **конструкторе**.

Comment: @Chorkov создайте ответ, я его помечу как "верный"

Comment: В вопросе задача должна быть описана так, чтобы было понятно, чего хочет автор.

Comment: @alexolut автор четко описал чего хочет, при чем тут инициализирующий конструктор?

Comment: Никак. Движок кодогенерации С++ не настолько силен чтобы сделать такую фишку. Конец.

Comment: @Maxmaxmaximus передайте автору чтобы почитал ответ и особо обратил внимание на функцию `f`.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант очистки структуры на базе [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/624067/176217), ранее упомянутого в комментарии:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define STRUCT_FIELDS \
    X(int, i) \
    X(double, d) \
    X(std::string, c) 

struct S {
    #define X(type, name) type name;
        STRUCT_FIELDS
    #undef X
};

template<typename T> 
void f(T& t)
{
    t = T();
}

void clear(S& s) {
    #define X(type, name) f(s.name);
        STRUCT_FIELDS
    #undef X
}

int main() {
    S s { 1, 42.1, "c" };

    std::cout << s.i << "[" << s.c << "]" << s.d << "\n";
    clear(s);
    std::cout << s.i << "[" << s.c << "]" << s.d << "\n";;
}
```

[Результат выполнения:](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UAFtoUvzKratykTu)

> ```
> 1[c]42.1
> 0[]0
> ```